# Instruct Windows Task Scheduler to turn on the monitor from sleep

Tags: windows, windows-vista, task-scheduler

How do I get Windows Task Scheduler to turn on the monitor from sleep in Windows Vista?
Currently, all it does is wake up from sleep (without turning on the monitor, it runs a batch script).

Comment: Not sure if it will work, but if the monitor just requires mouse movement or a keystroke, write a little AutoIt or AutoHotKey script to jiggle the mouse a bit or hit a few keys and have task scheduler run that.

Comment: Hello Sam, would you like [edit] this question and add some detail.  In its current form it is unanswerable.  You are saying that you want it to "turn on from sleep" and that it "wakes up from sleep", which is contradictory.

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice utility called [NirCmd](https://nircmd.nirsoft.net/) that can do this. Set your action to run this command:

```
nircmd.exe sendkeypress ctrl
```

`nircmd.exe monitor on` doesn't always work, [but `sendkeypress` seems to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40880446/8166701).

To test that this is working, set up a custom trigger for a few minutes from now, and then run `nircmd.exe monitor off` (or set your monitor timeout to 1 minute and just wait).

Comment: this works well in Windows 11, even on hybrid graphics systems, with nircmdc.exe as well (console version)

Answer (score 0):

If the monitor is physically turned off then its not possible for software to do this without some kind of specialized hardware.  However, if the monitor has just gone blank then you could have it execute a useless program or a batch file with simply an `exit` command.